# Grouped or stacked barplot in R

Tags: r, r-markdown, project

I have a school project where I have to build graphs in R. Wanted to do a grouped or stacked barplot for data of parliament.

```
Year = c(2016, 2017, 2018, 2019)
Men = c(107, 99, 99, 86)
Women = c(33, 411, 41, 36)
Parliament = data.frame(Year, Men, Women)
```

Basically I want to show the difference of the parliament representation in the given years, but I don't know how to.
If anyone could help me with the code, please?
Thank you.

Comment: It is unlikely that people here want to solve your homework. Google "R stacked barchart" and try to adapt what you find. If that does not work out, come here with a specific question, showing what you did yourself. That is going to be better in almost respect.

Comment: I did that but couldn't understand how to adapt the code, that's why I came here. 
I thought someone could help me quicker

Comment: The question is always, what is the aim of the school project: learning R programming or use of R for a given visualization problem,.

@Selina Balla: have a look at the example and try to understand what `t()` does. It can also be possible, that there is a simpler solution.

Comment: Use of R for a given problem, it's mathematical engineering and the language is used in statistics class that's why  I needed it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here one way how to do this, if it is a school project, please have a look at the corresponding help pages to understand the code. And it would be even better, to improve it:

```
Year       <- c(2016, 2017, 2018, 2019)
Men        <- c(107, 99, 99, 86)
Women      <- c(33, 411, 41, 36)
Parliament <- data.frame(Year, Men, Women)

barplot(as.matrix(t(Parliament[c("Men", "Women")])),
  names.arg=Parliament$Year, legend=c("Man", "Women"))
```

Comment: Thank you @tpetzoldt

Comment: My pleasure. Next time, please show what you did, even in case it is wrong, so that people can better see how to help.

Comment: I will keep that in mind. Thank you very much